# Boost Beast error basic_socket_acceptor

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming

I'm trying to follow a simple example from boost beast, I am using boost v1.58.0 and beast from repository v124.

Here is my server start code:

```
void server::start () {
    try {
        auto const addr = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(bind_addr);
        boost::asio::io_service ioc{1};
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acc_{ioc, {addr, port}};
        std::list<worker> webworkers;
        for (int i=0;i<workers;i++) {
            webworkers.emplace_back(acc_,doc_root);
            webworkers.back().start();
        }

        if (spin) {
            for(;;) ioc.poll();
        } else {
            ioc.run();
        }

    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "WebServer Failure: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile my code, I get the following error:

https://pastebin.com/GdN8DMEX

i am following the this example:

https://github.com/boostorg/beast/tree/develop/example/http/server/fast

Answer (score 0):

This line is trying to copy a `basic_acceptor`, which is not a CopyConstructible type:

```
webworkers.emplace_back(acc_,doc_root);
```

Try moving a newly constructor acceptor instead:

```
webworkers.emplace_back(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor{ioc, {addr, port}},doc_root);
```